# Packages: question about order of with statements

Tags: ada

I have a short question: It is safe to sort [*with clauses*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-1-2.html) in package specifications and bodies in ascending order for easier readability of the source code?

A simple example:

Not sorted:

```ada
with D;
with A;
with C.X;
with B; use B;
```

Sorted:

```ada
with A;
with B; use B;
with C.X;
with D;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t believe that the order of context clauses makes any difference. Of course, you have to have `with`ed a unit before you can `use` it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [10.1.4](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-1-4.html) and [10.2.1](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-10-2-1.html) can gave you more information.

The compiler do the job of the order of units (when it can). In case where it didn't (or you want a specific order) you can use pragmas (see 10.2.1).